# Is there a way to list blobs in AzureBlobStorage based on timestamp?

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I want to programmatically list all blobs created in the Azure storage container after a certain time? Is there a way to list only those blob files?

Answer (score 3):

Currently, there is no direct way to list blobs after a certain time.

There're 2 workarounds here.

1.List all the blobs first -> fetch the creation time of each blob -> compare the creation time of the blob with the certain time. Like below:

```
myblobs = container_client.list_blobs()

#define a filter date or timestamp as per your need.
filter_date = "2021-01-18 or 2021-01-18 01:31:29"

for blob in myblobs:
    #compare the creation time of blob with the filter_date
    if str(blob.creation_time) > filter_date:
        print(blob.name + ":" + str(blob.creation_time))
```

2.When create a blob, you can specify a prefix for your blob. The prefix can be defined as year-month-date(or you can add hour, minutes etc). Then when you list blobs by using `list_blobs()` method, there is a parameter `name_starts_with`. At this time, you can specify a date for `name_starts_with` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

If you like Powershell:

```
$daysAgo = 30
# this example uses OAuth token, you can change it to use a SAS token or account key
$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName MyStorageAccount -UseConnectedAccount

# Get all blobs in container, get the Name and CreatedOn date
# then filter by days old and sort by descending date
Get-AzStorageBlob -Context $ctx -Container MyContainer | `
  Select-Object Name, @{L="CreatedOn"; E={$_.BlobProperties.CreatedOn}} | `
  Where-Object CreatedOn -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-$daysAgo) | `
  Sort-Object CreatedOn -Descending
```

***IMPORTANT:*** You must be a Storage Account Blob Contributor on the account. I'm a subscription owner, but this didn't work on my account until I added this role. There may be other roles that work, but don't assume your subscription or resource group-level roles will work here.

Comment: I am looking from python or the SDK support. Thanks !

Comment: Since the question was open-ended, I used my weapon of choice. Might want to let others know on the question!